# What's wrong with this css?

Tags: css

**[Here's the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/WSvW4/)**

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    top: 138px;
    bottom: 158px;
    left: 33px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I wouldn't think that the div should be only 30px tall, not 60

Comment: Wouldn't that be predicated on the height of the container?

Comment: Why would it only be 30? You are defining that on the element it is in. So its 138 from the top and 158 from the bottom.

Comment: Oh so I need a `top` and a `height` right?

Comment: Like @Matt says, you don't define a height, only the distance from the top and bottom of the containing element. Hence, my comment. :)

Comment: @ qwertymk: *"Oh so I need a top and a height right?"* If you want to control where the top of the element is and its height, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying both `top` and `bottom`, you're making the element's height get dictated by the height of its parent element. It'll be as tall as necessary to be 138px from the top and 158px from the bottom of it.

If you want to control where the top of the element is and its height, specify `top` and `height` rather than `top` and `bottom`.

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:30px;
    left: 33px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder you don't need top, unless he wants x amount of pixels from the top. If he just wants a set height, then use height.

Comment: Without `top`, it'll default to the top of the window. I'm pretty sure that's not what he/she is looking for.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder yea from his comments, sounds like its a logo where he sets the background image on the div to a picture. He wants to set the width and height of that div and then set the top x pixels from the top of the window. So yea, in his case he would need top.

Answer (score 1):

`bottom` specifies the distance from the bottom of the containing element (the window, for `absolute` positioned boxes, I think) to the bottom of the described element - not from the top of the containing element.

To specify a height, use the `height` property.

Comment: Seriously, I didn't even really know - I just went to the fiddle and played around with the numbers and other property names. CSS is stupidly complex overall, but simple examples are usually not hard to figure out anyway. Get into the debugging spirit :)

Answer (score 0):

you dont't need to have `top` and `bottom`. One is fine

if a div is 400px long, and you have an element inside with the top set to 50px, the bottom will automatically be set to the remainder. So you only need to set one of them.

Note if the height: is not set, the div does not occupy any space.

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:30px;
    top: 138px;
    left: 33px;
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The height is dependent on the position; imagine 3 points, placed where you have specified (`top, left, bottom`) and moving while you resize the page. The div will change height according to these points. Specifying only `left` and `top` has no effect on the height.

The problem is you used `top` or `bottom` instead of a height.

Comment: Height has nothing to do with top, left, right, or bottom, they only position an element inside a parent element.

Comment: @Jason - Except it does in certain cases. Danae should have said `top` *and* `bottom`, but it *may* affect the height. See: http://jsfiddle.net/WSvW4/5/ and try resizing the bottom, right frame.

Comment: Probably should have been more specific? In this particular case, the height is affected by the position he's defined?